# Reference an element at time t in t+1 in a fast way

Tags: r

The 40 in a[1,2]at t should flow into a[2,1] at t+1.
I tried it with a loop (see #test), as the elements 
will change constantly.

Is there an optimal solutions also pertaining to speed? 
In the end this loop must run through thousands of i and j.
My loop does not achieve my goal.

Any ideas?

Here the example:

```
#Example
a <-c(10,40)
a <- matrix(a, ncol=2, nrow =1)
a <- rbind(a,c(0,0))


#Test
for (i in 2:3) {
for (j in 1:3){
    a[i,1] <- a[j,2] 
  }
}
```

Here the Start / and Result that I try to create:

```
START <- matrix(c(10,40, 0, 0), ncol=2, nrow =2, byrow = TRUE)
RESULT <- matrix(c(10,40, 40, 0), ncol=2, nrow =2)
```

Comment: Please provide an example input and output. It's very hard to tell from your description what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The end result should be :  Row 1: (10, 40)  Row 2: (40 , ) The 40 comes from the first row and is just transferred as a first element into the second row.

Comment: Your loop does not result in what you say you want.

Comment: Hi Matthew, you are correct. I was very unclear. I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially want to move `a[1:2, 2]` into `a[2:3, 1]` (your first example).  A general way of accomplishing this would be:

```
from <- 2L
to <- 1L
len <- dim(a)[1L]
if(len > 1)
{
    a[-1L, to] <- a[1L:(len - 1L), from]
}
```

Comment: Hello Jota, Thank you. That is what I wan't to achieve for a matrix with thousands of rows. I will use this and try to figure out if its fast enough. Thank you very much again.